# Large seed pod from Mediterranean region - identification

Tags: identification, seeds

The images are of a seed pod that came, either from Malta or Cyprus. It is about 60mm diameter and extremely hard. I had to take a hammer to it for it to open.
Inside were many small flat ,slightly fluffy heart shaped seeds.

Might anybody recognize it please?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Looks a lot like a [Jacaranda seed pod](https://www.google.com/search?q=jacaranda%20seed&num=20&safe=off&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihpa2J5r_TAhUl5IMKHSrNBSQQ_AUICCgB&biw=1184&bih=667).

[image: Jacaranda]

[Image from](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Jacaranda_mimosifolia_-_pods_and_seeds.JPG) wikimedia.
Looks like Jacaranda is [native to Malta](http://www.maltawildplants.com/BIGN/Jacaranda_mimosifolia.php), and at least grows in Cyprus.
It's also common in the San Francisco area.